# jquery edit comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, edit

Can you explain  the methods to make a jquery edit system where I click on a click and then it show a textarea and a edit bottom.

What is the best methods to do it?

Right now I have this:

```
<div id="frame">
<div id="data">bla bla bla</div>

<a class='edit' href=''>edit</a>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#frame a').click(function()
    {
        var data = $('#data').text();

        alert(data);
        console.log('press edit');
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way most sites do this, including StackOverflow, is by using the built in "design mode" capabilities of browsers.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) is an Open Source version of such an editor.

I modified your example, such that clicking on the edit link will make the "bla bla bla" text editable.

**Notice two things:**

1. The body tag has a new attribute, *designMode*, set to "on".
2. To enable editing, the data div has to have the *contentEditbale* attribute set to
   true.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the screenshot, I couldn't figure out how to post html in my response.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're almost there. If data to edit are very simple, you could just do something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('#frame a').click(function()
    {
        $('#frame').html('<form action="..." method="post"><textarea name="data">' + 
          $('#data').text() + 
          '</textarea><input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>');
    })
})
```

If the data to edit are more complex, you might consider to load them via AJAX or put the whole form to edit inside the html and hide it by default. If the user clicks the edit button, you just need to show it.

Comment: Thanks so much @iGEL, but will it be good to make a hidden div with the textarea etc. and then if the user click edit then put the div to display show and put the users data in the textarea?. and how do i check if the user have click the submit edit bottom :)?